# Textbox color does not persist on focus

Tags: css

I have created css button style as here: http://jsfiddle.net/karimkhan/SgTy2/

When I used same css insite `<style>` in my page then it's effect changed. looks like below:

[image]

Actual css on fiddle gives this kind of view:

[image]

I am not good at css. What's wrong I am doing here?

Comment: Add some class to these elements which are unique and apply this stylings. Here you are using element names in css which is not recommended.

Comment: Adding !important might solve your problem.

Comment: _“Here you are using element names in css which is not recommended”_ – way too general. Always depends on purpose and desired outcome.

Comment: You're confusing jsFiddle, stop before you break it!......There are 16 `<input>` tags on that one page. IDs and Classes have their uses, this being one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you make an external css file? 
The same will probably happen, so see what styles are overlapping your element in inspector mode. I would not suggest to use !important, but rather make the style have more priority. One way to do this is to make your css selector more specific. 
For example:

```
input[name="url"]
{
    background: black;
}
```

has more priority as

```
input
{
    background: red;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SgTy2/1/)

*Note that a more specifc path also takes longer to determ.*

 Hope you can work on a solution now.